# Почему текста с api не показываются в "посмотреть код страницы"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Почему текста с api не показываются в "посмотреть код страницы"?
Проект делаю на nuxt.js, api сделан на ruby

Делаю так:

```
async created() {

  const { data: { title } } = await axios.get('url')

  this.title = title 
}
```

Вроде же всё логично - я беру данные и вставляю в html до того, как страница приходит в браузер

Что делать? может ssr как-то не так работает?

Comment: код страницы вам показывается тот, который отрендерился на сервере, а результат манипуляций на фронте можно увидеть в дереве в веб инспекторе

Answer (score 0):

Подобного виды запросы надо делать в [asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data). Тогда с сервера будет приходить хтмл вместе с вставленным title, сможете увидеть в коде страницы.

Вот так будет выглядеть:

```
export default {
  async asyncData ({ params }) {
    let { data: { title } } = await axios.get('url')

    return { title } // возвращается объект который будет слит с data
  }
}
```

Comment: Выходит ошибка: C:\Users\user\Mun_front\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.esm.js:587 [Vue warn]: Property or method "title" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Section1> at components\Section1.vue
       <Pages\index.vue> at pages\index.vue
         <Nuxt>
           <Default> at layouts\default.vue
             <Root>

Comment: Такое чувство, будто он ничего не возвращает или не может вернуть, и тут дело не в апи(

Comment: Проверьте после деструктуризации { data: { title } } получило ли оно title, вроде бы как в доке написано

Comment: Она даже статические  данные возвращает, если поставить asyncData